# Availability of the Larkin's paper: Application of superconductivity theory methods to the problem of the masses of elementary particles (1961)

Tags: specific-reference, history, higgs

Discussing with colleagues (mostly condensed matter ones), we were astonished there is no mention about the work by Larkin in the [announcement of the Nobel Prize committee](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2013/advanced.html) this year.

The title of the Larkin's paper -- APPLICATION OF SUPERCONDUCTIVITY THEORY METHODS TO THE PROBLEM OF THE MASSES OF ELEMENTARY PARTICLES -- sounds promising, but I have no idea about its content. It seems to be extremely difficult to find. I'm not even sure it has been translated.

So the question is: can anyone provide me with the original publication, some translation in some west-european language, or some extracts of the original paper by Larkin ? [More details about this paper can be found following this link](http://www.osti.gov/scitech/biblio/4007891).

*This question does not intend to open any polemics regarding the attribution of this year Nobel prize. Larkin died in 2005 by the way.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, I found this review:

> [image]

<sup>[*Source*](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/scans.html?volume_=109&count_=217)</sup>

Thus, the paper appeared in two languages, Russian and English.

> [image]

<sup>[*Source*](http://www.itp.ac.ru/ru/persons/larkin-anatoly-ivanovich/)</sup>

Comment: Perfect :-) With that I'll be able to find the english translation next Monday. Thanks so much !

Comment: @Oaoa You'd expect both papers to appear [here](http://www.jetp.ac.ru/cgi-bin/e/index), but unfortunately the sought volumes aren't listed. :(